# While writing the JSON file getting the ERROR

Tags: json

I am writing the following code of JSON file for my use to POST it into my website

```
{
    fleetSubscriberId: 
        {
         subscriberId: "The subscriberId used during login",
         name: "Subscriber name",
         groupId: "Subscriber group ID",
         companyCode: "Subscriber company code"
        },
            fleetPolicySummaries: 
                [
                    {
                         policyNumber: "1234", companyCode: "456" 
                     }
                ],
        {
                "companyName": "Natural Resources Canada",
                "locations":
                [
                    {
                         "streetAddress": "580 Booth St 17th Fl Room a6",
                         "city": "Ottawa",
                         "stateOrProvince": "Ontario",
                         "country": "Canada"
                    }
                 ]
        }
}
```

It showing the following ERROR can any one help me in solve this

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{    fleetSubscriberId: 
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: You've changed the question to the new error you're getting, which could make my answer to the original problem obsolete. Please don't remove context. I'm rolling it back

Answer (score 0):

The field names are literals.

You should enquote field names, too (e.g. `"fleetSubscriberId":`) to make it valid JSON.

Comment: Now i am getting the above ERROR can u please help me

Comment: You've changed your question to something else. Have some consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Check this . I formatted your JSON. Note I added a new **"other"** as field names.

```
{
    "fleetSubscriberId": {
        "subscriberId": "The subscriberId used during login",
        "name": "Subscriber name",
        "groupId": "Subscriber group ID",
        "companyCode": "Subscriber company code"
    },
    "fleetPolicySummaries": [
        {
            "policyNumber": "1234",
            "companyCode": "456"
        }
    ],
    "other": {
        "companyName": "Natural Resources Canada",
        "locations": [
            {
                "streetAddress": "580 Booth St 17th Fl Room a6",
                "city": "Ottawa",
                "stateOrProvince": "Ontario",
                "country": "Canada"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check your json valid or not here. http://pro.jsonlint.com/ 
your json is not valid.